# Python how to handle hex char in serial.Serial

Tags: python, hex

I need a function to handle hex and str

Such like this

```
hex_str = ''
for i in ('123'):
    hex_str += '\x3'+i

print(hex_str)
```

The expected result is '\x31\x32\x33'
But it doesn't work.

And the hes_str would be typed into a serial.It should be treated like a hex

```
sel = serial_crt('/dev/tty.usbserial-FTCHMFWZ', 115200)
sel.write('\x05')
sel.write('\x02\x08'+hex_str+'\x03')
sel.write('\x04')
```

What can I do to fix it?

Tks

Comment: Tks anyway , it can't answer my question

Comment: this is not a good way for this purpose but it can help you  `for i in "123":
    hex_str += chr(int(i, 16))`

Answer (score 2):

To enter '\' as a character, you must enter '\' one more time.
'\' --> '\\' Like this.
Modify the code as follows:

```
hex_str = ''
for i in ('123'):
    hex_str += '\\x3'+i
print(hex_str)
```

Comment: If I use '\\". hex_str won't work in serial.Serial().write().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ord()` function to get the ASCII value of your input first then convert it into hexadecimal using `hex()` function. You need to use double backslash `\\x` to escape the `\x` in the output.

```
def generate_hex_str(input):
    hex_str = ''
    for i in input:
        hex_str += '\\x' + hex(ord(i))[2:]
    print(hex_str)
    return hex_str

generate_hex_str('123')
```

Comment: Great tks. It's close. But the hex_str won't be treated like hex data. I type hex_str into serial.Serial().write(). It doesn't work.